# eclipse and git: commit failed, how do I commit any new changes

Tags: eclipse, github

I am using Github through eclipse.  I commit my changes regularly and they show up in github when I go to the web browser and look up my github account.  I did a commit today and there was some kind of error.  My new changes are not showing up in github and I cannot commit anything, no changes are registered.  I did not save what the error was.  Is there a way to force eclipse to check the repository against my local repo and find new changes so I can commit them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes were committed to your local repository, but because of the error, were not pushed to remote repo (Github server).  So, as far as git is concerned, they are "committed".  You can try a push, which pushes local commits to remote repo, which should print the errors if it failed.  Most likely failure is that there were other commits done to the remote repo which you have not pulled into your local repo.  I'd suggest:

- Pull latest from remote repo to local repo
- Push commits from local    repo to remote repo

If you see no errors in Eclipse, then get web browser to see if on Github server.

If still errors, then someone possible changed the same file you did, and there is a merge conflict, which you'll have to reconcile (which I find one of the most difficult things with eGit(

Comment: Thank you!  I restarted eclipse and the push worked.